# Mix and match horizontal and vertical form styles in antd 5

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I have a form that I want to be in vertical mode.
In it, there's a row with a bunch of checkboxes. I think the checkboxes look bad in horizontal, so I'd like to use the vertical layout just for that row.

I used to do this in antd 4 by adding an overridding css class.

Here is what the snippit of form items within the vertical form looks like:

```
<Row className="horizontal-override">
          <Form.Item name="Available" label="Available" valuePropName="checked">
            <Checkbox onChange={onInputChange} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Divider type="vertical" />
          <Form.Item name="ShipHomeOnly" label="ShipHome Only" valuePropName="checked">
            <Checkbox onChange={onInputChange} />
          </Form.Item>
          ...//More of the same
</Row>
```

The overriding css I had been using in 4 looks like this:

```
.ant-form{
  .horizontal-override{
    .ant-form-item{
      flex-direction: inherit;
      label{
        display: inline-flex;
        height: 32px;
        margin-right: 4px;
        align-items: center;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This css would mimic the styles the form did if it was horizontal just for the row of checkboxes.

Now in antd version 5, the styling has changed drastically, and I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: Perhaps your current css styles will work, you just need to add `!important` at end of each style prop so antd will not override this style and then see if it's styled as you want. E.g.:`display: inline-flex !important; ..... etc`

Comment: @NoNam4 Nope, they still have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In antd, if you need to override styles in css, you need to search for classes inside dev console. It's very anoing but it's the only way at this momment.

In your case you need to change `ant-form-item-row` instead. I suppose in v5 devs added an extra `div` in layout:

```
.horizontal-override > .ant-form-item {
  flex-direction: inherit;

  .ant-form-item-row {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 32px;
    flex-direction: row,
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```

I still would suggest you to put `!important` after each style so you'll make sure antd will not override this styles.

Also [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-9-4-forked-wxfdqy) you can find a working codesandbox example.

Comment: Thank you, I was going crosseyed trying to figure out where the difference lied.